# Sharepoint files permissions

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

I have some problem inside Sharepoint 2010. I have some library and all files inside this library have unique permissions. I don't know why. It this library I have thousands of files.  Only files are affected. All folder inherit permissions from library. I have a very lot of folders, and next folders inside, and next and next and next. Right now I have to go to all folders, click on each file and click "Document Permissions" and then "Inherit Permissions". When I select 2 files Document Permissions option is disabled.

Can I change permissions for all files inside all folders just like in Windows? In windows I need to check one checkBox when I changing permissions to some folder.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to mess with folders; modifying the Library Settings -> Permissions should fix your issue. This documentation should get you all the information you need: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-permissions-for-a-list-library-or-individual-item-5b900de3-9123-41c9-aa04-919ae6606d40

Comment: It doesn't work. Changing library permissions doesn't change single files permissions. They are still unique